# Great difficulty interacting with a RESTful storage server via Ruby

Tags: ruby, rest

I am using an S3-like storage server EMC called ATMOS. I have tried to access this server following examples in both the multipart-post gem and the rest_client gem.

The only response I am ever able to receive is "400 - bad request".  The server is active and my headers at least appear to be in order.

I just don't know where to turn to troubleshoot this after trying for 16 hours. I am very, very frustrated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Google's sake:  there is a proper [Ruby wrapper](https://code.google.com/p/atmos-ruby/) for Atmos now.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, some actual information. After trying a bunch of different things, very complicated things, I found [this post](http://snippets.aktagon.com/snippets/141-How-to-perform-a-file-upload-multipart-post-with-Ruby).

require 'rest_client'
RestClient.post "http://myserver.com", headers.merge(:file => File.new('/Users/me/sample.jpg'))

I am going to pin a medal on this guy. Ping me if you're experiencing similar problems, I feel like I wrote Net::Http by now.